# Problem with Ckeditor in Symfony 3.4 app when deploying on Heroku

Tags: php, symfony, heroku, ckeditor

Ckeditor didn't appear when I deploy it to Heroku but it is working perfectly at local.

How can I fix it?

**Error in Console:**

[image: error in console]

Thanks in advance.
Lucas.

Comment: Try to debug, when you discover what is wrong you will be able to fix it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP, How to debug in Heroku production? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about Heroku, however the error in console indicates that ckeditor is missing, maybe you have it in local but not up.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP, that is my problem, when I deploy in heroku, he is in charge of doing everything and apparently he would not be loading the libraries of the CKeditor. Heroku lifts a kind of container when deploying, and relies on the composer.json file to install all the dependencies.
Have you worked with Heroku? It is not an FTP.
Thanks and regards!

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't work with Heroku.

Comment: @LucasMartín have you solved this problem ? let me know please.